# Multiple entry with the ID in php TABL

Tags: php

How can I create multiple entries with the same ID in my database? For example in this table named `STUDENT`:

```
 STUDID  |   Name    |   Training
    1    | John Mots |   Leadership training
    1    | John Mots |   Computer Troubleshooting
    1    | John Mots |   Programming 
    2    | Marivic   |   Networking
    2    | Marivic   |   C++ Programming
```

Comment: @inetphantom He never even mentioned any database. It could even be NoSQL for all we know.

Comment: store it in a file, get in on a variable, call explode on `|`. fastest solution :D

Comment: Before creating your database, do some research on "normalization".  https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Database_normalization

Comment: What database are you using?

Answer (score 0):

You have a table which is not in the third normal form. Google [normalization](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Normalization) for further information.

What you have to do is create a table `student` with your student info. Then create a table `training` with all your available trainings. Then make a Jointable `student_has_training`, with the foreign keys to each of those tables. In that table you can now store which student has which training.

Now if you want the table you showed, you can use (in case of SQL)

```
Select * from student as 's'
join student_has training as 'st' on s.idstudent = st.student_idstudent 
join training as 't' on t.idtraining = st.training_idtraining;
```

Comment: You cannot simply *guess* what kind of database he is using.

Comment: i used it as primary key the ID but not autoincrement

Comment: how you consider this as an Answer/Solution ?

Comment: yes sir jeff noel sample i have table name "ENTRY" the existing program i have is that ID, NAME, TRANING1, TRAINING2, TRAING3.... pls help if i can use one field only for training

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. To critique or request clarification from an author, leave a comment below their post.

Comment: @Reeno the question changed, now the answer changed too. This was the right answer to the first edition of his question.